# Angular, watch specific keys in object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wondering if it's possible to just watch a specific key in an array of objects, so instead of

```
 $scope.$watch('data', function (newValue) {
```

would it be possible to do something like

```
    $scope.$watch('data.name', function (newValue) {
```

This would be in an array, so the desired functionality woud be if the any of the data[i].name items change it would fire?

Don't know of something like this would be possible. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1) Shallow watch over the `Array` (with `$watchCollection`), like this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('data.name', function (newValue) {...});
```

2) Deep watch over the `Array`, like this:

```
$scope.$watch('data.name', function (newValue) {...}, true);
```

With option 1 the `$watch` function will only get triggered if you are adding/removing elements, but not if you are making changes into one of the `Array` elements.

On the other hand with option 2, the `$watch` function will run every time that there is any change.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$scope.$watchCollection('data', function (newValue) {...});` and `$scope.$watch('data', function (newValue) {...}, true);`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what you're trying to do from http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/choroshin/2014/03/26/angularjs-watch-for-changes-in-specific-object-property/.

```
var app=angular.module('App', []);
function ctrl($scope){
$scope.count=0;
$scope.people = [{id:1,name: "bill"}, {id:2,name: "jim"}, {id:3,name: "ryan"}]

$scope.$watch(function($scope) {
  return $scope.people.
      map(function(obj) {
        return obj.name
      });
}, function (newVal) {
    $scope.count++;
    $scope.msg = 'person name was changed'+ $scope.count;
}, true);
}
```

This watches the name property on each object as you can see from the map function returning obj.name.